# Cell Component not re-rendering on Board in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Edit

I was able to start getting the cells to rerender, but only after adding `setCellsSelected` on line 106. Not sure why this is working now, react is confusing.

#### Summary

Currently I am trying to create a visualization of depth first search in React. The search itself is working but the cell components are not re-rendering to show that they have been searched

[image]

It starts at the cell in the top left and checks cells to the right or down. Once a cell is searched, it should turn green. My `cells` array state is changing at the board level, so I assumed that the board would re-render but to no avail. For now I am only searching the cells straight below `(0,0)` as a test.

### Code

`Board.js`

```js
const Cell = (props) => {

  let cellStyle; // changes based on props.value
  if (props.value === 3) cellStyle = "cell found";
  else if (props.value === 2) cellStyle = "cell searched";
  else if (props.value === 1) cellStyle = "cell selected";
  else cellStyle = "cell";

  return <div className={cellStyle} onClick={() => props.selectCell()}></div>;
};

const Board = () => {

  // 0 = not searched
  // 1 = selected
  // 2 = searched
  // 3 = selected found
  const [cells, setCells] = useState([
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
    new Array(10).fill(0),
  ]); // array of cells that we will search through, based on xy coordinates
  const [start, setStart] = useState("00");

  const selectCell = (x, y) => {
    // Make sure to copy current arrays and add to it
    let copyCells = [...cells];
    copyCells[x][y] = 1;
    setCells(copyCells);
  };

  const renderCell = (x, y) => {
    return (
      <Cell
        key={`${x}${y}`}
        value={cells[x][y]}
        selectCell={() => selectCell(x, y)}
      />
    );
  };

  const renderBoard = () => {
    let board = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
      let row = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        let cell = renderCell(i, j);
        row.push(cell);
      }
      let newRow = (
        <div className="row" key={i}>
          {row}
        </div>
      );
      board.push(newRow);
    }
    return board;
  };

  const startSearch = () => {
    // start with our current startingCell
    const startX = parseInt(start[0]);
    const startY = parseInt(start[1]);

    let copyCells = [...cells];
    const searchCell = (x, y) => {
      console.log("Coordinate:", x, y);
      if (x >= cells.length) return;
      if (y >= cells.length) return;
      let currentCell = copyCells[x][y];
      console.log(copyCells);
      if (currentCell === 1) {
        copyCells[x][y] = 3;
        console.log("Found!");
        console.log(x, y);
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("Not Found");
        copyCells[x][y] = 2;
        setTimeout(() => {
          searchCell(x + 1, y);
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(searchCell(x, y + 1), 3000);
      }
    setCells(copyCells);
    setCellsSelected(['12']) // this works for some reason
    };
    searchCell(startX, startY);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ margin: "25px auto", width: "fit-content" }}>
        <h3>Change search algorithm here!</h3>
        <button onClick={() => startSearch()}>Start</button>
      </div>
      <div className="board">{renderBoard()}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-cartwright-qldiw

The first issue is that you are doing setStates inside a long running function. Try instead keeping a search state and update the location instead of calling recursively.

The other issue is at the `selectCell` function

you are copying the rows by reference(`let copyCells = [...cells];`), so when you change the cell (`copyCells[x][y] = 1;`) you are also changing the original row, so the diffing will say the state did not change.

```
  const selectCell = (x, y) => {
    // Make sure to copy current arrays and add to it
    let copyCells = [...cells];
    copyCells[x][y] = 1;
    setCells(copyCells);
  };
```

try changing to `let copyCells = [...cells.map(row=>[...row])];`